# Joomla 5..0.3 delay in search

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, sitecore, delay

Joomla 5.0.3 there is a strong delay in the administrative panel of the content search function.

Delay in searching menu item, user too. There is no such effect in the frontal part. I assume that for this reason the problem is not in the hosting, not in the DBMS, but in Joomla. On the same hosting, in the same environment, early versions of Joomla. 5. Provided quick search. Has anyone encountered a similar phenomenon?